# How to render 20% of a pdf with custom pdf viewer created with pdf.js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

This is the code that is responsible to get the pdf. It then passes the pdf to the pdf viewer for it to be rendered. I don't want to render the whole pdf. Instead, I want to render just part of the pdf, for example, the first 5 pages, or 20% of the page. The code below uses pdfjs and this code below is available in the PDFJS repo. You can access the entire code via https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/mobile-viewer/viewer.js

```
private open (params) {
    let url = params.url
    let self = this
    this.setTitleUsingUrl(url)
    // Loading document.
    let loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
      url: url,
      withCredentials: true,
      maxImageSize: MAX_IMAGE_SIZE,
      cMapPacked: CMAP_PACKED
    })
    this.pdfLoadingTask = loadingTask

    loadingTask.onProgress = function (progressData) {
      self.progress(progressData.loaded / progressData.total)
    }

    return loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdfDocument) {
      // Document loaded, specifying document for the viewer.
      console.log(pdfDocument); // The pdf object. picture content below

      // The document is being passed to the viewer for rendering
      // I want to pass just 15% of the document to the user to view
      self.pdfDocument = pdfDocument;
      self.pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument)
      self.pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdfDocument)
      self.pdfHistory.initialize(pdfDocument.fingerprint)
      self.loadingBar.hide()
      self.setTitleUsingMetadata(pdfDocument)
    }
```

The image below is the structure of the pdf object

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest a package [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf). It is a wrapper of pdf.js. The document has props `onLoadSuccess` as a function with object as an argument. As I know in this object you can find `numPages` - the total number of pages. You can manipulate this number like Math.floor(0.2*numPages) and render only this number of pages. However, read documentation MB you can find a better solution.

UPDATE:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages: Math.floor(0.2 * numPages) });
  }

  render() {
    const { numPages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Document
          file="somefile.pdf"
          onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          {Array.from({length: numPages}, (v, i) => i).map(i => (
            <Page key={i} pageIndex={i} />
          ))}
        </Document>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't get react-pdf to work. It keeps saying that "failed to load pdf" I will love if you can help me with that.

Comment: I cannot help, sorry. [here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/tree/master/sample) you can find examples.